# Save YouTube Playlist Offline

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, offline

Is it possible to download or save a YouTube Playlist so that is can be viewed while offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube's premium service, [YouTube Red](https://www.youtube.com/red), allows this in the [YouTube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en), [YouTube Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.music&hl=en), and [YouTube Gaming](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.gaming&hl=en) apps.

Once you are subscribed to YouTube Red ($1.99/month), you will see an "Add to offline" button below videos, this will allow you to download the video at your selected quality so that it can be viewed offline.

Source: [Using YouTube Red benefits](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6308116?hl=en)